# Splitting large files efficiently (currently using awk)

Tags: bash, awk, split

I have a 4 GB file that I need to do some operations on.  I have a Bash script to do this, but it Bash seems ill suited to reading large data files into an array.  So I decided to break up my file with awk.

My current script is :

```
for((i=0; i<100; i++)); do awk -v i=$i 'BEGIN{binsize=60000}{if(binsize*i < NR && NR <= binsize*(i+1)){print}}END{}' my_large_file.txt &> my_large_file_split$i.fastq; done
```

However the problem with this script is that it will read in and loop through this large file 100 times (which presumably will lead to about 400GB of IO).

QUESTION : Is there better strategy of reading in the the large file once?  Perhaps doing the writing to files within awk instead of redirecting its output?

Comment: Why not just use `split(1)`?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable solution also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `binsize` is the number of lines you want per chunk, you could just maintain and reset a line counter as you step through the file, and setting alternate output files within awk instead of using the shell to redirect.

```
awk -v binsize=60000 '
  BEGIN {
    outfile="output_chunk_1.txt"
  }
  count > binsize {
    if (filenum>1) {
      close(outfile)
    }
    filenum++
    outfile="output_chunk_" filenum ".txt"
    count=0
  }
  {
    count++
    print > outfile
  }
' my_large_file.txt
```

I haven't actually tested this code, so if it doesn't work verbatim, at least it should give you an idea of a strategy to use. :-)

The idea is that we'll step through the file, updating a filename in a variable whenever our line count for a chunk exceeds `binsize`.  Note that the `close(outfile)` isn't strictly necessary, as awk will of course close any open files when it exits, but it may save you a few bytes of memory per open file handle (which will only be significant if you have many many output files).

---

That said, you could do almost exactly the same thing in bash alone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

binsize=60000

filenum=1; count=0

while read -r line; do

  if [ $count -gt $binsize ]; then
    ((filenum++))
    count=0
  fi

  ((count++))

  outfile="output_chunk_${filenum}.txt"
  printf '%s\n' "$line" >> $outfile

done < my_large_file.txt
```

(Also untested.)

And while I'd *expect* the awk solution to be faster than bash, it might not hurt to do your own benchmarks. :)

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test your specific script, but the key to outputting awk to separate files is `outfile="output_chunk_" filenum ".txt"` and `print > outfile` (which I utilized in solving this problem).  Compared to my original script (which I projected taking 800 minutes) this method takes about 30 minutes to complete.  Thanks!