# awk split files and keep the filename

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Using awk to split up files into chunks of 5000 lines for each file and rename them sequentially. I need to keep the original file name as part of the extension so that they don't overwrite the previously split files.  That's why I'm attempting to do this inline.

I'm getting an error on the periods in the file extensions.  I have tried using variables and multiple ways of quoting.  I am running this command in a loop via Bash shell

```
input_file="$(basename "${file}")"
gawk 'NR%5000==1{x=../library-extract/msplit-bib/temp/'"${input_file}"'++i.split.xml;}{print > x}'
```

I am getting syntax errors on all of the periods in the file extensions

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting large files efficiently (currently using awk)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505402/splitting-large-files-efficiently-currently-using-awk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk requires literal strings to be quoted:

```
gawk -v f="$input_file" '
    NR%5000==1 {x = "../library-extract/msplit-bib/temp/" f (++i) ".split.xml"}
    {print > x}
'
```

The parentheses around `(++i)` are required to ensure `f ++i` is not treated like `f plus positive i`

or

```
gawk -v f="../library-extract/msplit-bib/temp/$input_file/%d.split.xml" '
    NR%5000==1 {x = sprintf(f, ++i)}
    {print > x}
'
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the process is hanging on the awk script.

Comment: Are you forgetting to give gawk a file to read? Is gawk happily reading (nothing)  from stdin?

Comment: YES!  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can do the same with `split` (without full control on file names but it's a simple `rename`)

```
split -l 5000 -da 3 filepath prefix.
```

where you can set prefix the same as filepath.  Option `-da 3` sets numeric extension with 3 digits.